# Florida: what is the deadline to appeal a decision by a state agency, and what is the venue?

Tags: florida, administrative-law

I wish to file an appeal for a decision issued by an enforcement agency (1). Which section of [Chapter 120](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0100-0199/0120/0120ContentsIndex.html) if any specifies the timeline? I skimmed through the chapter and did not find it.

I  thought DOAH would be the appropriate venue. , but then I read [rule 28-106.201](https://www.flrules.org/gateway/RuleNo.asp?title=DECISIONS%20DETERMINING%20SUBSTANTIAL%20INTERESTS&ID=28-106.201) reproduced below which would seem to indicate Initiation of Proceedings is made with the agency having issued the decision to appeal.

Some clarification welcomed.

> DOAH is a state agency that employs full-time Administrative Law
> Judges to conduct hearings in most cases in which the substantial
> interests of a person are determined by an agency and which involve a
> disputed issue of material fact.
> https://www.doah.state.fl.us/ALJ/RepresentYourself.asp

> 120.569 Decisions which affect substantial interests.— (1) The provisions of this section apply in all proceedings in which the
> substantial interests of a party are determined by an agency, unless
> the parties are proceeding under s. 120.573 or s. 120.574. Unless
> waived by all parties, s. 120.57(1) applies whenever the proceeding
> involves a disputed issue of material fact.
> http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0100-0199/0120/Sections/0120.569.html

> 28-106.201 Initiation of Proceedings.
> (1) Unless otherwise provided by statute, and except for agency
> enforcement and disciplinary actions that shall be initiated under
> Rule 28-106.2015, F.A.C., initiation of proceedings shall be made by
> written petition to the agency responsible for rendering final agency
> action. The term “petition” includes any document that requests an
> evidentiary proceeding and asserts the existence of a disputed issue
> of material fact. Each petition shall be legible and on 8 1/2 by 11
> inch white paper. Unless printed, the impression shall be on one side
> of the paper only and lines shall be double-spaced.

Resources:

[Primer on FL's APA / Florida Bar](https://www-media.floridabar.org/uploads/2021/11/PocketGuideFloridaAPA.pdf)

[Appealing Administrative Action: The Threshold Considerations](https://www.floridabar.org/the-florida-bar-journal/appealing-administrative-action-the-threshold-considerations/)

Update:

(1) And more specifically a decision by DBPR's RE division, in response to a complaint for violations of chapters 475 and 83 (Tenant-Landlord).

(2) The Agency is the right venue, their clerk's office confirmed.

Comment: I don't know enough to offer an answer but your [DOAH Link](https://www.doah.state.fl.us/ALJ/RepresentYourself.asp) includes this "*the final decision is not in your favor, you have the right to appeal to an appropriate District Court of Appeal within 30 days of the date of the Final Order. The Florida Rules of Appellate Procedure provide the procedures for filing the appeal.*"

Comment: @rick That's after DOAH has rendered its judgment, and it is not what I am asking.

Comment: I'm still looking, but it may help if you name the agency you wish to appeal so I can look at their policies, procedures, rules etc

Comment: @rick Department of Business and Professional Regulation /  Florida Real Estate Commission. The relevant chapters are 455 and 475.

Comment: This is a quite tricky area of law (the U.S. Supreme Court takes a case every year or two on this issue at the federal issue). Some go to a trial court, some go to the court of appeals, and some are a proper appeal while others are petitions for writ of certiorari in a trial court, with a strict jurisdictional deadline set by court rule. The exact thing appealed matters a lot.